# Moving caret position within text field

Tags: javascript, firefox, webdriver

I'm attempting to write browser tests for a customised input field (it's an Angular directive, though I don't think that's relevant), and I'm having trouble with moving the cursor within the field.

The situation that was found that if a user types a value into the field, then hits home and enters another value, that was appearing at the end rather than the start of the field. The code has been fixed, but now I'm trying to add tests to cover it.

A simplified version of the code I'm using is as follows:

```
driver.sendKeys('555');
driver.sendKeys(webdriver.Key.HOME);
driver.sendKeys('1');
assert.equal(getFieldValue(), '1555');
```

Unfortunately, sending the Home key appears to do nothing. It's not a timing issue between the Home key and the rest, as if I look at the browser while it's in flight, I can see that the cursor has not moved.

Any suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my solution as an answer, though not marking it as such since it doesn't solve the Webdriver issue.

I ended up running a Javascript function along the lines of the following in order to move the cursor to the start of the field:

```
driver.executeScript("$('#field-under-test')[0].setSelectionRange(0,0)");
```